# Is it possible to use a 2009 imac as a display for a 2017 macbook pro?

Tags: display, imac

Is it possible to use a 2009 imac as a display for a 2017 macbook pro? If so, what cable would I need to make this work? Ideally with a mini display port to usb-c cable it would just work but I have my doubts.

Comment: @Allan I saw that in the search, but I think this is different, since I'm using a 2017 mbp with the usb c connections.

Comment: It's actually the same question.  The 2017 MBP doesn't have a USB-C port.  It has a Thunderbolt Type C port which has Thunderbolt and DisplayPort signals so you need still need either a DP cable or a TB cable.  There's even a link in the answer that takes you to Apple's page that confirms this.

Comment: Looks like USB C to me, and it charges my usbc phone. Are you sure? I think it is usb c.

Comment: USB-C is the physical connector type (thus the "Type C" designation).  A [Thunderbolt 3 port](https://thunderbolttechnology.net/blog/thunderbolt-3-usb-c-does-it-all) is a Type C port which supports PCIe, DisplayPort, USB 3.1, and Power Delivery.  Apple actually incorrectly says it's a USB-C port that support Thunderbolt, which is impossible because it's the other way around.  This is partly why this whole thing is confusing to everyone.

Comment: @Allan So physically I will need:
1) usb-c to mini-display port dongle
2) mini-display port cable

Comment: There's that confusion I was referencing (and not a single ounce being your fault)!  The moment you use the "USB" word, "dongle" is sure to follow which is what you *don't* need.  You just need a [Thunderbolt 3 to mini DisplayPort cable](https://amzn.to/2RFBiYx) and that's assuming you're using a 27" iMac (this is not possible on the 20" model).

Answer (score 0):

[image: setup]

It appears you are describing the setup above. This is possible to do.

You will need a **Mini DisplayPort to Mini DisplayPort** cable and a **Mini DisplayPort or Thunderbolt** port on your MacBook Pro.

To start using your iMac as a display you need to **enter Target Display Mode.**

> Follow these steps to start using your iMac as a display:
>
> Make sure that your iMac is turned on,  and the other Mac is logged in
> to a  macOS user account.
>
> Connect the Mini DisplayPort or  Thunderbolt cable between the two
> computers.     Press Command-F2 on the  keyboard of the iMac that you
> want to  use as a display.

([Source](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204592))

**To exit Target Display Mode:**

> To leave Target Display Mode, press Command-F2 on the iMac keyboard again. Your iMac also exits Target Display Mode if you disconnect the cable that connects the two computers, or if you shut down or sleep either computer.
>
> If the connected Mac goes into sleep mode, the iMac screen turns off until you wake the other computer, or until you take your iMac out of Target Display Mode.

**Using Apps**

> Any apps that are open on your iMac remain open and active while your iMac is in Target Display Mode.
>
> For example, if you begin playing music in iTunes on your iMac and then activate Target Display Mode, iTunes doesn't pause on your iMac.
> If you've set your iMac to automatically log out, apps are paused or closed when this happens but your iMac remains in Target Display Mode.

**Connecting devices to your ports**

> A Mac that's connected to an iMac in Target Display Mode can't use the iMac computer's built-in camera, its USB, ThunderBolt, or FireWire ports, or devices connected to those ports. To use external devices with your Mac, connect these devices directly to the Mac that you want to use them with.

Comment: I don't believe it is quite the same, as that is an older mbp, not the 2017 model with usb c.

Comment: @DarthEgregious you can use thunderbolt